# Magento - E-mail is blank after updating template

Tags: magento, email, templates

We are changing our e-mail templates in Magento. And after changing them, for some reason, the entire e-mail is blank. The only thing we changed is the order of the items and the HTML itself.

We did NOT change any other file, only this one.

Anybody any idea what is going wrong?

PS: we are running Magento 1.4.0.1, upgrading is not an option atm.

Thanks in Advance.

### OLD FILE:

```
<!--@subject url.nl: Nieuwe bestelling # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->

<style type="text/css">
    body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>

<div style="font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="98%" style="margin-top:10px; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;">
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">

        <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <p>
Beste {{var order.getCustomerName()}},<br/><p>
                    Bedankt voor uw bestelling bij Company. Gedurende uw bestelling wordt u op de hoogte gehouden van de laatste ontwikkeling van uw status.
                        U kunt de status van uw bestelling controleren door  <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">in te loggen op uw account</a>.
</p>

                    <h3 style="border-bottom:2px solid #eee; font-size:1.05em; padding-bottom:1px; ">Uw bestelling #{{var order.increment_id}} <small>(geplaatst op {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}})</small></h3>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="48.5%" bgcolor="#dfe6dc" style="padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-bottom:none; line-height:1em;">Factuurgegevens:</th>
                            <th width="3%"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="48.5%" bgcolor="#dfe6dc" style="padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-bottom:none; line-height:1em;">Betaalmethode:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-top:0; background:#f8f7f5;">
                                {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-top:0; background:#f8f7f5;">
                                {{var payment_html}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="48.5%" bgcolor="#dfe6dc" style="padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-bottom:none; line-height:1em;">Verzendinformatie:</th>
                            <th width="3%"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="48.5%" bgcolor="#dfe6dc" style="padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-bottom:none; line-height:1em;">Verzendmethode:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-top:0; background:#f8f7f5;">
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border:1px solid #ede7e7; border-top:0; background:#f8f7f5;">
                                {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{/depend}}
                    {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

                    {{var items_html}}
                    <br/>

                    {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
<p>Wij hopen dat er naar tevredenheid word behandeld en zien u graag in de toekomst terug bij een volgende bestelling bij Company.
<p>Heeft u nog vragen? Stuur dan een e-mail naar <a style="color: rgb(30, 126, 200);" href="mailto:bestelinfo@url.nl">bestelinfo@url.nl</a> </p>
Met vriendelijke groet,

                </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- [ header starts here] -->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="url.nl"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

### NEW FILE:

```
<!--@subject url.nl: Nieuwe bestelling # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->

<style type="text/css">
    body { margin:0px; }
</style>

<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; background: url({{skin url='images/si/bg-top.png' _area='frontend'}}) top left repeat-x, url({{skin url='images/si/bg.png' _area='frontend'}}) top right repeat;">

<div style="width:690px; background-color:#f6f6f6; border-radius: 10px; position:relative; top:45px; box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px 0px #ccc; left:50%; margin-left:-345px;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="670px;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="385" height="105px;"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/logo.png" _area='frontend'}}"></a></td>
    <td width="125" style="color:#111; font-size:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <strong>Companyname</strong><br />
    Street 28<br />
    1234 AB City
    </td>
    <td width="20"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/tel_mail_web.png" _area='frontend'}}"></td>
    <td width="140" style="color:#111; font-size:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    030-1234567
    info@url.nl
    www.url.nl
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#c8c8c8" height="1"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:20px; color:#000; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    Beste {{var order.getCustomerName()}},<br/>
    <p>
    Bedankt voor uw bestelling bij Company. Gedurende uw bestelling wordt u op de hoogte gehouden van de laatste ontwikkeling van de status van uw bestelling. U kunt de status van uw bestelling altijd zelf in de gaten houden door  <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#000;">in te loggen op uw account</a>.</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650px;" align="center" style="border:1px solid #6E9300; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;" bgcolor="#99CC00" height="28px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="325" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Uw bestelling #{{var order.increment_id}}</strong></td>
        <td width="325" style="padding-right:10px;" align="right"><small>(geplaatst op {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}})</small></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650px;" align="center" style="margin-top:4px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:#000; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

        {{var items_html}}

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br>

    {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}

    <br><br>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650px;" align="center" style="border:1px solid #6E9300; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;" bgcolor="#99CC00" height="28px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="215" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Factuuradres:</strong></td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#6E9300"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="215" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Verzendadres:</strong></td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#6E9300"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="216" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Betaalwijze:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650px;" align="center" style="border:1px solid #c5c5c5; color:#000; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:4px;" bgcolor="#fff" height="28px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="215" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;" valign="top">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="215" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;" valign="top">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="216" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;" valign="top">{{var payment_html}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="215" height="1" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="215" border="0"></td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="215" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="215" border="0"></td>
        <td width="1" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="1" border="0"></td>
        <td width="216" bgcolor="#c5c5c5"><img src="{{skin url="images/mailings/px.gif" _area='frontend'}}" height="1" width="216" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;">
        <strong>Verzendwijze:</strong><br>
        {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/depend}}
    </table>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:20px; color:#000; font-size:11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    Wij hopen dat er naar tevredenheid word behandeld en zien u graag in de toekomst terug bij een volgende bestelling bij Company.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="690px;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" background="{{skin url='images/mailings/footer.png' _area='frontend'}}" height="102" style="padding-left:30px; font-size:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #7AA230;">
    <strong>
    Heeft u vragen? Neem gerust contact met ons op:<br><br>
    &nbsp; · Website: via het contactformulier. <a href="{{store url="contacts/"}}" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:underline;">mail ons</a><br>
    &nbsp; · Telefoon: 010-752351 (van maandag t/m vrijdag tussen 8.30 en 17.00 uur)
    </strong>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with 1.4. Do you have an area in the administration panel to create the templates? Do that instead. In 1.5+ at least, you'll find it in System -> Transactional Emails

Comment: Hi Zachary, thanks for the suggestion. But the e-mails I need to change are actually not listed there. I'm not sure why, and how. Because the initial installation was done by another company. But I cannot change them there. So I need to change them in the source documents. And for some reason this is giving the current problems.

Comment: Cannot change them how? Does the template save? If it does, you still need to tell Magento to use the template. In Mage 1.5+ you are able to do this by going to System -> Configuration, and then going to Sales -> Sales Emails.

Comment: Hi Zachary, this did the trick. Still strange that the same template, by replacing the default file doesn't work. But doing the same HTML through the admin works. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chtck file encoding. Must be UTF-8

Comment: That must have been the problem. Thanks!